# How to query MongoDb documents using the indices of embedded arrays

Tags: mongodb, express, typescript

I am trying to learn how to use mongo queries to reach deep into a data tree. Specifically, I'm trying to remove the object below `{"object": 'to remove'}`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("7840f22736341b09154f7ebf"),
    "username" : "nmay",
    "fname" : "Nate",
    "lname" : "May",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "monthNum" : 1,
            "year" : 2016,
            "days" : [ 
                {
                    "date" : "2016-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
                    "type1" : [],
                    "type2" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : "2016-01-02T06:00:00.000Z",
                    "type1" : [
                       {"object": 'to remove'}
                    ],
                    "type2" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so far I know how to query for the user `_id`, but I'm not sure how to remove the desired object using the indices in each array. In this example I want to remove `data[0].days[1].type1[0]`

Here is the query that I have so far:

```
app.delete('/user/:id/data/:monthIndex/days/:dayIndex/type1/:type1Index', function (req, res, next) {
  var monthIndex = parseInt(req.params.monthIndex); // these console the value properly
  var dayIndex = parseInt(req.params.dayIndex); // -1 is applied to the parameter to translate to array position
  var type1Index = parseInt(req.params.type1Index);

  db.users.update(
     { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
     { $pull: data.monthIndex.days.dayIndex.type1.type1Index }
   );
}
```

It gives me the error

> ReferenceError: data is not defined

**Can someone demonstrate how I can pass this query my index parameters to remove the desired object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove an array element by its numerical index with a single operation in MongoDB. In order to do this, you need to unset desired element(s) first, and remove the resulting `null`-valued fields afterwards.

Your code should look something like this:

```
db.users.update(
    { _id : mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { $unset : { 'data.0.days.1.type1.0' : 1 } }
);
db.users.update(
    { _id : mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { $pull : { 'data.0.days.1.type1' : null } }
);
```

Edit by @bob: to pass in the parameters you have to build the query string, which is ugly:

```
var unset = {};
unset['$unset'] = {};
unset.$unset['data.' + req.params.monthIndex + '.days.' + req.params.dayIndex + '.foods.' + req.params.foodIndex] = 1;

db.users.update( { _id : mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, unset );

var pull = {};
pull['$pull'] = {};
pull.$pull['data.' + req.params.monthIndex + '.days.' + req.params.dayIndex + '.foods'] = null;

db.users.update( { _id : mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, pull );
```

Comment: this works with hard coded index numbers, but how can I pass in a number?

Comment: @NateMay I have never worked with Express/Typescript, so I honestly have no idea what is the proper syntax to concatenate strings with variables in this language. In plain JavaScript this would look like `'data.' + monthIndex + '.days.' + dayIndex + '.type1.' + type1Index`, maybe this will work for you as well.

Comment: Just build the query dynamically. Also`update` is deprecated. Use`updateOne` or `updateMany`.

Comment: @NateMay I have left your edit almost intact, but note that when you pull an element from the array, you actually do **not** want to indicate any indices, as the query will resolve them by itself. If you want to remove more than one element, you still need only one pull operation, because it removes every element that evaluates to `null`.